# ubuntu locale difference between zh_CN.utf8 and zh_CN.UTF-8

Tags: locale, utf-8

There are some questions about Linux locale confused me much.

What is the difference between `zh_CN.utf8` and `zh_CN.UTF-8` ?

Are they the same locale ?

Run `locale` command:

```
LANG=zh_CN.UTF-8  
LANGUAGE=  
LC_CTYPE="zh_CN.UTF-8"  
LC_NUMERIC=zh_CN.UTF-8  
LC_TIME=zh_CN.UTF-8
```

Run `locale -a` command:

```
C  
C.UTF-8  
en_AG  
en_AG.utf8  
POSIX  
zh_CN.gbk  
zh_CN.utf8  
POSIX
```

Anther two question:

What is the difference between C and `C.UTF-8` ?
What is the difference between `en_AG` and `en_AG.UTF-8` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file `/usr/share/i18n/SUPPORTED` lists locales that are supported in Ubuntu with their correct names along with encoding.

- zh_CN.UTF-8 is the correct name, and zh_CN.utf8 is an alias that refers to the same locale.
- C, unlike C.UTF-8, enables usascii encoding.
- en_AG is the correct name, even if en_AG.UTF-8 is a working locale name that refers to the same locale.

Comment: In file `/usr/share/i18n/SUPPORTED`, I see the following two lines:  
- en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8  
- en_US ISO-8859-1  
Does it means that locale `en_US` uses `ISO-8859-1` encoding and `en_US.UTF-8` uses `UTF-8` encoding?  May I use `en_US.ISO-8859-1` as the alias of `en_US`?   <br/>
And the most important one, how does Ubuntu determine the real locale from the alias?

Comment: 1: Yes; 2: Don't know; 3: Don't know - Please don't ask new questions in comments.

Comment: `zh_CN.UTF-8 is the correct name, and zh_CN.utf8 is an alias that refers to the same locale`, I was very confused by the alias when I was trying to automate locale setup. Is there a alias file define that? I didn't see this in /etc/locale.alias. Or `UTF-8` and `utf8` are interchangeable when systems load locale name?

Comment: @guoqiao: Please ask a question as a new question, not as a comment on an old answer.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the difference between en_AG and en_AG.UTF-8 ?

`en_AG`Not having character encoding facility , so it must look up when encoding needed. but `en_AG.UTF-8` have character encoding , so it will take care of encoded characters when it needs to do.

Comment: Not correct. en_AG is the correct name of the English language locale for Antigua and Barbuda, and it enables UTF-8 encoding.